# Which browsers claim to support HTTP compression but are actually flaky?

Tags: http, compression

Are there any known issues with older/buggy browsers that claim to support gzip/deflate compression but don't handle it very well?  I'm obviously only turning it on for browsers that claim to support it, but for the best user experience, I want to know if there are any browsers I should blacklist.

For some reason, I remember hearing problems about IE6 and gzip, but I'm not sure what the details were.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some links to documents that name some browsers that don’t support compression though claiming it:

- [Apache’s sample configuration in the mod_deflate module documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#recommended)
- [Which browsers can handle `Content-Encoding: gzip`?](http://schroepl.net/projekte/mod_gzip/browser.htm)

Comment: That second link is dated 2003-03-11. More recent browser versions (in particular IE6 SP1) which may have bug fixes are not covered.

Answer (score 1):

The IE6 problem was that before IE6sp1 it could lose the first 2048 bytes of data in a compressed response: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;Q312496

Answer (score 1):

Citing user Greg Dan's answer from question [What is the problem with this ajax(with prototype)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517799/what-is-the-problem-with-this-ajaxwith-prototype/537443#537443):

*Sometime ago I read about IE and Apache gzip module problems. It was occurring only on local installations where a server response was very fast.*

Never tried anything like that myself, only read that answer recently. Maybe it helps.